# How to correctly style functional components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a following functional component and it works as expected.

```
<template functional>
    <div>
        <input />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "FunctionalComponent"
}
</script>

<style scoped>
input {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
```

However, it looks like Vue has some issues with scoped styles. In vue devtools, I see this `AnonymousComponent` rendering and in console I get some errors. If I remove style tag, then it works fine.

Is it expected or I am doing something wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What version are you using? see: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-xsy58

Comment: @acdcjunior You did. Goto: https://xsy58.csb.app/ and open Vue devtools and you can use one console error and `AnonymousComponent`.

Comment: Try to remove name property from Vue component

Comment: @Sanjay oh, now I saw it. I got it when, using "Vue Devtools" plugin, I opened the `FunctionalComponent` in the tree. Before that, no error popped up. Can you confirm if this is your case as well? If this is so, then I think the bug is in "Vue Devtools", not Vue itself.

Comment: @acdcjunior Yeah it happens when I click that component in Vue Devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug on vue-devtools.

The only way (for the current version - 5.1.1) to not have the error is to make the component *not* `functional`.

An issue was created: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1067

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with scoped styles I suspect. Your "export default" components don't define there own name. You name them in the importing file. Try removing the name element of your component. (I too am having trouble reproducing. I don't see the error in the console when I switch to that frame in codesandbox.)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The sandbox code does reproduce the error. Goto https://xsy58.csb.app/ and then on Vue developer tools. You can see functional component and if you expand that it shows "AnonymousComponent". Now, when you click it, you get an error called "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: Just to verify, I removed scoped styles. Now, it doesn't show "AnonymousComponent" anymore.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/XVEBPubHZBjaeSYB8
https://photos.app.goo.gl/tqqVReHZbLqFnDFa9